# What is the relation between cookies and the Rails session object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This method remembers users by storing an encrypted cookie in the user's browser:

```rb
  def remember_user
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.encrypted[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent.encrypted[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end
```

How is the following method able to read the `user_id` from the session object if I am storing it in cookies?

```
def index
    @user = User.find session[:user_id]
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This whole question is based on a completely bogus premise that is easily disproven.

```
get 'cookie_monster/set_cookie'
get 'cookie_monster/eat_cookie'
```

```
class CookieMonsterController < ApplicationController
  def set_cookie
    cookies.permanent.encrypted[:x] = 999
    redirect_to action: :eat_cookie
  end

  def eat_cookie
    render plain: "session[:x] is #{session[:x].inspect} not #{ cookies.permanent.encrypted[:x] }"
  end
end
```

```
require 'test_helper'

class CookieMonsterTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "the session is not the same thing as cookies.encrypted" do
    get "cookie_monster/set_cookie"
    follow_redirect!
    assert_equal "session[:x] is nil not 999", response.body
  end
end
```

The session is stored in separate session storage cookie. This is basically a hash like object that's serialized and then de-serialized on each request.

When you do `cookies.permanent.encrypted[:user_id]` you're setting a completely different cookie.

Comment: I'm 99% sure you're actually just calling `session[:user_id] = @user.id` somewhere in your code.

Comment: yes you were right, dont know how i missed that, thanks for your detailed answer